# MVC Search Boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an MVC View that should allow the user to search by either id number or last name.  They would enter id in the id textbox or last name in the last name textbox.  Right now with the code I have, it will only work if you enter in both an id and a last name, or only an id number.

Here's the code in my controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(collection["ID_NUM"]);
            string last = collection["LAST_NAME"];


            var ViewResults = new CombinedModels();

ViewResults.ADDRESS_MASTER = (from e in db.ADDRESS_MASTER
                                          where e.ID_NUM == id
                                          select e).FirstOrDefault();

            ViewResults.NAME_AND_ADDRESS = (from n in db.NAME_AND_ADDRESS
                where n.ID_NUM == id || n.LAST_NAME == last
                select n).FirstOrDefault();


            return View(ViewResults);
        }
```

The second LINQ statement is the one I'm trying to use for my search.

Here is my view.

```
@*@model JHelpWebTest2.Models.NAME_AND_ADDRESS*@
@model JHelpWebTest2.Models.CombinedModels



<link href="~/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/images/dragonball3.ico">

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "JHelp";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "JHelp"))
{
    <section class="section1">
        <div>
            <label>Union ID</label>
            @Html.TextBox("ID_NUM")           
            <label>Last Name</label>
            @Html.TextBox("LAST_NAME")
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/><br/>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section1">
        <div class="divWidth">
            <label>Password</label>
            @Html.TextBox("Password")
        </div>
        <div class="divWidth">
            <input type="submit" value="Update"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Reset"/>
        </div>
    </section>
    if (Model != null)
    {
        <section class="section1">
            <section class="section2">
                <div>
                    <label class="alignLabel">First Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.FIRST_NAME, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})
                    <label class="alignLabel">Last Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.LAST_NAME, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section2">
                <div class="divWidth">
                    <label class="alignLabel">Prefix</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.PREFIX, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">Preferred Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.PREFERRED_NAME, new { @class = "alignTextBox", size="5" })
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section2">
                <div class="divWidth">
                    <label class="alignLabel">Suffix</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.SUFFIX, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">Middle Name</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.MIDDLE_NAME, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})
                </div>
                </section>
        </section>
        <section class="specialsection">
            <section class="section2">
                <div class="divWidth">
                    <label class="alignLabel">Address Line 1</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.ADDR_LINE_1, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">Address Line 2</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.ADDR_LINE_2, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">Address Line 3</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.ADDR_LINE_3, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">City, State Zip Code</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.CITY, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.STATE, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.ZIP)
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section2">
                <div class="divWidth">
                    <label class="alignLabel">Phone</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.PHONE_NUM, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">Ext</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.PHONE_EXT, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">Country</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.COUNTRY, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                    <label class="alignLabel">County</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME_AND_ADDRESS.COUNTY, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section2">
                <div class="divWidth">
                    @*@if (Model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_CDE == "*EML")
                    {
                        <label class="alignLabel">*EML</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br/>
                        <label class="alignLabel">eALT</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("eALT")<br />
                        <label class="alignLabel">eLRN</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("eLRN")

                    }
                    else if (Model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_CDE =="EALT")
                    {
                        <label class="alignLabel">*EML</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("*EML")<br/>
                        <label class="alignLabel">eALT</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})<br />
                        <label class="alignLabel">eLRN</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("eLRN")
                    }
                    else if (Model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_CDE == "ELRN")
                    {
                        <label class="alignLabel">eLRN</label>
                        <label class="alignLabel">*EML</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("*EML")<br/>
                        <label class="alignLabel">eALT</label><br/>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1, new { @class="alignTextBox", size="5"})
                    }*@
                @switch (Model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_CDE)
                {
                    case "*EML" : 
                        <label>*EML</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1)<br/>
                        <label>eALT</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("eALT")<br />
                        <label>eLRN</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("eLRN")
                        break;

                    case "EALT" : 
                        <label>*EML</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("*EML")<br/>
                        <label>eALT</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1)<br />
                        <label>eLRN</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("eLRN")
                        break;

                    case "ELRN" : 
                        <label>eLRN</label>
                        <label>*EML</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("*EML")<br/>
                        <label>eALT</label><br/>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1)
                        break;
                }
                @*<label>*EML</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1)<br/>
                <label>eALT</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1)<br/>
                <label>eLRN</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADDRESS_MASTER.ADDR_LINE_1)*@

        </div>
        </section>
        </section>
        <section class="section1">
            <div>
                <label>Registration Status</label>



            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </section>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user can optionally enter either an id, last name, or both, then you need to dynamically construct your query. Something along the lines of:

```
int? id = null;
Int32.TryParse(collection["ID_NUM"], out id);
string last = collection["LAST_NAME"];

...

var nameAndAddresses = db.NAME_AND_ADDRESS;
if (id.HasValue)
{
    nameAndAddresses = nameAndAddresses.Where(m => m.ID_NUM == id.Value);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last))
{
    nameAndAddress = nameAndAddresses.Where(m => m.LAST_NAME == last);
}

ViewResults.NAME_AND_ADDRESS = nameAndAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: I switched your id code above to use `Int32.TryParse`, which is safer. As you have it currently, with `Convert.ToInt32`, if the id comes back as anything but an integer, you app will crash.

**UPDATE**

There's one of the dangers of using extensions. I don't tend to use `TryParse` directly, because of the sort of awkward code it requires. It has to be passed an int, not a nullable int. So, you can do something like the following instead:

```
int id;
bool validId = Int32.TryParse(collection["ID_NUM"], out id);

...

if (validId)
{
    nameAndAddresses = nameAndAddresses.Where(m => m.ID_NUM == id);
}
```

As far as your other error goes, the only forseeable cause of that would be if your actual model property was of type `DbSet<NAME_AND_ADDRESS>`. You shouldn't do that. `DbSet<T>` should only be used in the context. In your view models and such you should using something like `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.  I am getting a couple error messages though.  On Int32.TryParse(collection["ID_NUM"], out id); On out id I'm getting the 'out' argument type doesn't match the parameter type.  Then on nameAndAddresses = nameAndAddresses.Where(m => m.ID_NUM == id.Value);  I'm getting the error message Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<JHelpWebTest2.Models.NAME_AND_ADDRESS>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<JHelpWebTest2.Models.NAME_AND_ADDRESS>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) I'm not sure what to do with these.